# Packaging multiple components that are shared with other apps

Tags: android

I'm planning to deploy several applications that will share a single 'Core Functionality Helper' component and would like to avoid requiring users to install two "apps" (e.g. 'Core' + 'Plug-in Component X') to get started. I'd also like to avoid duplication of the 'Helper' component code on the user's device when two or more components are installed.

So there would be many valid installations. For example some of the valid installations on a device might be -

1. Core + Plug-in A
2. Core + Plug-in B
3. Core + Plug-in A + Plug-in B
4. Core + Plug-in A + Plug-in B + Plug-in C

All components will have user interfaces and the Core will include at least one widget into which the other components will "plug in" from the user's perspective.

In the market I would like to offer "Plug-in A", "Plug-in B", etc. separately, and not force the user to have to independently install the "Core App". Silly as it may seem, I think it turns off users to have to install **two** "Apps" the first time they want to get the functionality provided by **one** of the plug-ins.

Since that kind of dynamic conditional packaging of apps into a single apk in the market is not possible today, my question is this -

Is there an elegant and efficient way to accomplish this kind of modular UI design without having to ask the user to install (and eventually update) two apps the first time?  (And of course we don't want a lot of duplication of code on the device.)

---

edit: I've edited the question above extensively to make it more clear. My original use of the term 'Component' was unfortunate as these are not necessarily Android code components (i.e. Activities, Providers, Services, etc.). I've used the term "Plug-in" in the edits above to be clear that this is all for user convenience at install time and to avoid duplicate code on the user's device.

Comment: This is a question I have dealt with myself. Android is not really made for this kind of *sharing* between applications - which actually is a design principle of Android for security reasons. Despite the fact that you may have a hard time trying to "remove" a part of an *installed* application, you may want to have a look at: a) services, b) content providers, and maybe c) custom classloaders.

Comment: To the contrary, Android is very well suited to this kind of sharing. The whole Intent architecture is designed for this. The question is how to package the components for distribution in a way that reduces complexity and confusion for the users.

Comment: ... and how an application can manage other applications' installed components, unpublish 'foreign' services in favor of its own, verify the authenticity of other applications' components, etc. - Nothing that would go too well with Android's security architecture. - Maybe also have a look at, e.g., [this](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2009/06/controlling-application-separation.html) and note Android's sharedUserId.

Comment: Thanks Hanno.  I think that your suggestion of using sharedUserId indeed gets me where I want to go when combined with ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE that was added in ICS. Can you post an answer so I can check it, or should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I've concluded that this can not be done elegantly from the user's perspective.

The most appropriate way to achieve the objective is to package the Core app separately and when a user installs one of the plugins then use an intent to test whether the Core is present. If it is not then direct the user to the marketplace where they can install the Core app.
Marking this as closed but if a better answer emerges I'll update.